# keycloak and social-auth-app-django : how to get user's groups

Tags: django, oauth, pipeline, keycloak, python-social-auth

My setup: docker containers for web and keycloak.

web container:
Django 2.2

social-auth-app-django==3.1.0

social-auth-core==3.2.0

keycloak container: pulled `jboss/keycloak` image.

The question is about the code:
I am using `social-auth-app-django` (not `python-keycloak`), login and logout are already functional. Is there a call that would give me the list of groups that the user belongs to (of course I am talking about not "django" users and groups but "keycloak" users and groups, which were set up via keycloak admin interface)? I have my `pipelines.py` file where I am trying to create a custom pipeline to pull this info out of `user` and `backend` objects, e.g.

`print("backend.get_user", backend.get_user(user_id))`

this gives me back:

> {'username': 'xxxx', 'email': 'xxxx', 'fullname': 'xxxx',
>   'first_name': 'xxxx', 'last_name': 'xxxx'}

and

`print("backend.extra_data", backend.extra_data(user, user_id, response))`
gives me back

> {'auth_time': 1579705033, 'access_token': 'xxxx', 'token_type':
>   'bearer'}

several other things I tried do not return groups information.
The documentation [Python Social Auth’s documentation](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) did not help.

How do I get the list of groups for a given user using whatever is available in social-auth-app-django?

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented in API keycloak docs, I found the solution by guessing what this could be :-) .

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % token}
groups_request = r
hequests.get('http://yoursite:8080/auth/admin/realms/<realm_name>/users/<user_id>/groups', headers=headers)
```